# Permanently add a firewall exception on Windows 7

Tags: windows, firewall

I'm using Windows 7 32-bits and on every start-up, a Windows security alert popup is displayed and I need to authorize the programs to access the network.

[image]

If I accept the popup, the program can access the network but on next startup, the popup is displayed again.

How authorize the program to **permanently** access the network ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Search for "Windows Firewall".
3. Click the link that shows up below.
4. Click the link on the left saying "Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall".
5. Find your program on the list and check its corresponding checkbox.
6. Click ok.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Click the "Unblock" button in the Windows security alert popup is exactly the same as what you describe and it doesn't **permanently** authorize the program to access the network ...

Comment: @LoicG - Your program may use a different program id each time it runs. In that case, there may not be much you can do. I would suggest possibly trying to find a different program to use in place of this one. Good luck!

Comment: The problem appear also with Skype. Others people seems to don't have this issue by using Skype so I don't think the problem is with the program used.